# How can I manipulate and make byte arrays?

Tags: java

I'm creating packets, and I need to encode bytes into an array for output. I have not been able to find any convenient classes to buffer the bytes in a variable length array, and then output them as an array of bytes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ByteArrayOutputStream` write bytes into it, and then call `toBytes()` to get the bytes.

Comment: And you can subclass 'ByteArrayOutputStream' to expose the underlying protected array reference and current length and to avoid having to uselessly duplicating the array just to get it out of the BAOS.